# How to get row from TableView?

Tags: java, for-loop, colors, tableview

I am creating a lobby application which will show all groups on a java tableview. Users are able to join groups that have space in them, else they will not be able to join.

I have been able to create this but I would like to be able to colour the row of the groups that have space in them in green and groups that are full will be coloured in red.

I will provide my code for this below. I am getting NullPointerException, which i dont know why. Thanks.

```
private void visualGroupAvailability() {
        boolean isThereSpace;

       for (currentGroupsModel o : groupsTable.getItems()) {
           TableRow<currentGroupsModel> currentRow = getTableRow(o.getGroupID());
             int limit = o.getNumberOfUsers();
             isThereSpace = checkSpaceInGroup(o);
             if(isThereSpace) {
                  currentRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #" + "388e3c ");
             } else {
                 currentRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #" + "ffcdd2 ");
             }
        }
    }

private TableRow<currentGroupsModel> getTableRow(int rowIndex) {
    Set<Node> tableRowCell = groupsTable.lookupAll(".table-row-cell");
    TableRow<currentGroupsModel> row = null;
    for (Node tableRow : tableRowCell) {
        TableRow<currentGroupsModel> r = (TableRow<currentGroupsModel>) tableRow;
            row = r;  
    }
    return row;
}
```

public class currentGroupsModel {

String groupName, groupDescription, hostName, groupType;
Integer numberOfUsers, groupID;

```
public currentGroupsModel(String gName, String gDesc, String hostName, String groupType, Integer numberOfUsers, Integer groupID){
    this.groupName = gName;
    this.groupDescription = gDesc;
    this.hostName = hostName;
    this.groupType = groupType;
    this.numberOfUsers = numberOfUsers;
    this.groupID = groupID;
}

public String getGroupName() {
    return groupName;
}

public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
    this.groupName = groupName;
}

public String getGroupDescription() {
    return groupDescription;
}

public void setGroupDescription(String groupDescription) {
    this.groupDescription = groupDescription;
}

public String getHostName() {
    return hostName;
}

public void setHostName(String hostName) {
    this.hostName = hostName;
}

public String getGroupType() {
    return groupType;
}

public void setGroupType(String groupType) {
    this.groupType = groupType;
}

public Integer getNumberOfUsers() {
    return numberOfUsers;
}

public void setNumberOfUsers(int numberOfUsers) {
    this.numberOfUsers = numberOfUsers;
}

public Integer getGroupID(){
    return this.groupID;
}

public void setGroupID(Integer newID){
    this.groupID = newID;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This question cannot really be answered with what you have given us. It is hard looking for a NullPointerException if there is a currentGroupModel we know nothing about and there are constant red hairings. For example why do you store something in limit, you never use it! Why do you pass getTableRow a rowIndex, that you are never using? As far as I get it your getTableRow returns the last TableRow in the table, not a specific one. Please consider fixing those problems first, before eventually providing some code to understand the inner workings of your currentGroupModel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have now updated the post the code the of the currentGroupModel class. Im trying to go through each row of the table and see if there is any room in the group, which i know how to do. I just need to know how i can select the row so i can change the background colour.

Comment: Thanks for the code of the currentGroupModel, but there is still a lot unclear; as i stated: Are you 100% sure getTableRow is correct, as in my eyes the rowIndex as well as the for-loop are useless. I could guess, that might be the origin of a NullPointerException. For a start, you could do worse than to post the line the compiler says is throwing the Exception

Comment: Hi, the method getTableRow() is my take on trying to get the table row but yes, it doesnt work. The line which is causing the nullpointerexception is this line - "currentRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #" + "388e3c ");" Therefore, i believe the problem is that getTableRow() is not returning a row object, causing the setStyle on the row to cause an exception.

Would you know how I can select a row from a tableview?

Comment: Unfortunately, Tables in Java (I guess you use java.swing for the table) aren’t that simple. They are organized loosely after the MVC-Concept, meaning, that you don’t change the data in the view, but in the model. That’s what a TableModel is normally used for, it is not like you’re currentGroupsModel a model for the entries of the table. So to answer your question: it is not possible (if it was it would be highly discouraged) to read or write data from/to tables via the table view. Create a class, that implements the TableModel interface and change data in there, then connect it to the view.